# How to make multiple if on matlab vector?

Tags: matlab

How to make multiple `if` on a **MATLAB** vector?

I have a vector as `score=[45,78,90]`
I am trying to print the grade for each student.
The expected result is:

```
fail
pass
pass
```

But my code doesn't work `result=score>=60:'pass':'fail'`

Comment: That use of the `:` looks like an attempt of a conditional operator, but the operator does something else: https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html Since you are not able to solve it without loops, have you tried solving it using loops instead?

Comment: Please don’t change your question after receiving answers, as it invalidates the answers. If you can’t manage to adjust the answers here yourself to your new problem, consider posting a new question. Do accept one of the answers that helped you most to show gratitude (also upvote once you have enough reputation).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
v = {'pass', 'fail'};
result = v((score >=60)+1);
```

which gives

```
result =
{
  [1,1] = pass
  [1,2] = fail
  [1,3] = fail
}
```

## **UPDATE 1**

If you have more conditions, maybe you can try the code below

```
score=[45,59,72,78,90];

v = {'A','B','F'};
[i,~,~]= find([score >=80; score>=60 & score<80; score <60]);
result = v(i);
```

such that

```
result =
{
  [1,1] = F
  [1,2] = F
  [1,3] = B
  [1,4] = B
  [1,5] = A
}
```

## **UPDATE 2**

For the output in the format of table, you can try

```
fprintf('%.2f\t',score)
fprintf('\n'); 
fprintf('%s \t',result{:});
fprintf('\n');
```

which gives

```
45.00   59.00   72.00   78.00   90.00
F       F       B       B       A
```

Comment: thanks a lot
if required grade is A,B,F
A if score>80
B from 6 to 80
F score<60

Comment: @EmanHusny you are welcome. if you think my answer is helpful, please feel free to upvote/accept it. thank you!

Comment: YES I WILL, last point how to print grade and score in tabular form as
45  F
78 B
90 A

my try: but is not good
fprintf('%.2f  ',Score);
fprintf('\n');
fprintf('%s ',result{:});
fprintf('\n');

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method using an auxiliary function to convert the marks to a cell array of strings, then printing the cell array of strings using `cellfun`.

```
function str = passfail(grade)
str = cell(size(grade));

for i = 1:length(grade)
    if grade(i) >= 60
        str{i} = 'pass';
    else
        str{i} = 'fail';
    end
end
end
```

Use as follows

```
>> cellfun(@(x) fprintf('%s\n', x), passfail([45,60,72,24]));

fail
pass
pass
fail
```

Comment: can solve without loop ? required grade is A,B,F A if score>80 B from 6 to 80 F score<60 ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use a loop?